# How to get rid of intialize member variable warning?

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is my code (simple Euclid's algorithm for GCD), It's working completely fine without any errors but why am I getting these warnings? what am I doing wrong?

warnings i am getting:
 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C26495  Variable 'EuclidAlgo::ch' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   EuclidAlgo  G:\VISUAL STUDIO\EUCLIDALGO\EUCLIDALGO\EUCLIDALGO.CPP   43
Warning C26495  Variable 'EuclidAlgo::num1' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). EuclidAlgo  G:\VISUAL STUDIO\EUCLIDALGO\EUCLIDALGO\EUCLIDALGO.CPP   43
Warning C26495  Variable 'EuclidAlgo::num2' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). EuclidAlgo  G:\VISUAL STUDIO\EUCLIDALGO\EUCLIDALGO\EUCLIDALGO.CPP   43
Warning C26495  Variable 'EuclidAlgo::temp' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). EuclidAlgo  G:\VISUAL STUDIO\EUCLIDALGO\EUCLIDALGO\EUCLIDALGO.CPP   43

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class EuclidAlgo
{
public:
    int m = 0, n = 0, r = 0, temp, num1, num2, ch;

    void input()
    {
        cout << "\nEnter two numbers to find their CDR : ";
        cin >> m;
        cin >> n;
        num1 = m;
        num2 = n;
    }

    void swap()
    {
        temp = m;
        m = n;
        n = temp;
    }

    void Algorithm()
    {
        if (n > m)
        {
            swap();
        }

        if (m % n == 0)
        {
            cout << "\n " << n << " is GCD of " << num1 << " and " << num2;
        }
        else
        {
            r = m % n;
            m = n;
            n = r;
            Algorithm();
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    EuclidAlgo o;

    o.input();
    o.Algorithm();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can remove these warnings
 by initialising `temp`, `num1`, `num2` and `ch` with values, the same way you've done for `m`, `n` and `r`. These warnings exist to stop you from accessing uninitialised memory and running into undefined behaviour.

Comment: `temp` and `r` are only used locally, so they should not be member variables.  `ch` is not used at all, and can be removed.

Comment: Actually i created ch to run a switch statement, this isn’t the complete code, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
int m = 0, n = 0, r = 0, temp, num1, num2, ch;
```

you haven't initialized the last four parameters.

In order to make the warning go away, simply initialize those four parameters, exactly like you did for the three first parameters, e.g.

```
int m = 0, n = 0, r = 0, temp = 0, num1 = 0, num2 = 0, ch = 0;
```

Comment: Oh okay, thanks a lot, now i have a clean code to submit in class.

Comment: @ChiragjotSingh you are welcome. I was about to update my answer, but the comments under your question are basically what I wanted to add, so I won't do it. If you found the answer helpful, then please accept it, if you'd like to of course.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize them like

```
temp =0, num1 =0 , num2 =0, ch =0;
```